# How to modify values in a csv file

Tags: python, csv

lets say I have a csv file with 5 values from 1 to 5, how could I divide each of them by 10 and save the csv file? I normally have thousands of values so I will need an automatic way of doing it.

So initial csv file is:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Output should be:

```
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5
```

I can read csv files in an array and save them but how do I modify each value in an array when I read them?

The lines I use to read and write are:

```
A = np.loadtxt("C:\\A.csv", delimiter=",")

np.savetxt("C:\\A.csv", A, delimiter = ",")
```

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work ?

Comment: I have edited my question to show what I use to read and write the csv files, but I don't know how to individually modify values in an array

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what `np` is ? Ok I guess it's `numpy` but that might be just anything. Anyway: your question is not about "modify values in a csv file" but about either "modifiy values in a numpy array" or "build a new numpy array with modified values". If there's a builtin way to do so in numpy it's certainly documented, else it's just like a list of lists.

Comment: Yes you are right, I have posted an answer to my question. I have managed to do it. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome - and glad to know you managed to solve it by yourself ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this and managed to do it:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.loadtxt("C:\\a_1.csv", delimiter=",")

for i in range(0, 10):
    A[i] = A[i]/10

np.savetxt("C:\\a_1.csv", A, delimiter = ",")
```

Comment: You should use `range(len(A))` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can first open the file in read mode. Then save the values in a variable and close the file. Modify the variables however you want to. Then open the file again this time in write mode and write then modified variable. This would overwrite the previous file. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's very fiddly to change values in place in a file.

The most straightforward approach is to read the file and write out the changes to a new file.

You can delete the old file and rename the new file afterwards if you no longer need the original values.